# Vimperator recommended setting

Tags: firefox, vim, vimperator

By way of study of Vim, I have begun to use [Vimperator add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891) recently.

Therefore please teach it if there is recommended setting.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 10):

Two settings are extremely useful, at least for me:

```
:set wildoption=auto
:set cpt=l
```

You can try them from vimperator command line first. After you type in the first one, you will see dynamic hints immediately, for example, if you continue to try the second command and to see what mean by 'l' . With wildoption on, you access to an item from the hint list by pressing Tab key, instead of arrow keys which would not work in most cases.

Another one I like is to set up my Bookmarks as sidebar by default, the command is:

```
:sidebar Bookmarks
```

One more trick after you have wildoptions on, you can access to FireFox menu items by typing:

```
:emenu [key_word]
# or
:em[tab]
```

where key_word is any menu key word such as Add-on.

I have several [blogs on vimperator](http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.com/2009/01/vimerator-settings.html) and how to set vimperator default settings.

Enjoy Vimperator. It is a great add-on for Firefox.

Comment: `wildoption` doesn't seem to exist in my v3.7.

Comment: I suspect he means `wildmode`

Comment: there is no auto for `wildmode`

Comment: I'm using Vimperator v3.9 and it seems to be `set wildmode autocomplete` for me.

Answer (score 6):

[Skypecakes suggested `b` and `B` to switch tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015518/89989); I prefer using `h` and `l`, since there's a good chance you switch tabs more often than you scroll horizontally:

```
noremap l gt
noremap h gT
```

Calling up Vim itself with `C-i` in a textarea is a must. [See here if you have trouble on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/189971/vimperator-setting-an-external-editor-in-windows-xp?lq=1)

```
set editor="C:/path/to/gvim.exe -f"
```

This is to customize how hints look in .vimperatorrc. The syntax is CSS, but you can probably figure it out without knowing it as well (I personally increase the font-size):

```
highlight! Hint font-family: monospace; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: white; background-color: red; border-color: ButtonShadow; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
```

Finally, if you set the working directory you can save URLs to that location with a simple `:w<Enter>`:

```
cd C:/Users/GGustafson/Desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really. One of the remarkable characteristics of Vim (and Vimperator) is providing a pretty decent experience with the default configuration. What I would suggest you to do is to play around with macros `(q)` and hinting `(f)`, the best, IMHO, features of Vimperator.

There are numerous examples of interesting macros, being my favourite the one that opens all the images on all tabs, each expanding into a new tab with the corresponding images. Try to write it! You'll need just markers and some javascript similar to Pornzilla's "Linked Images"

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Pentadactyl - which is almost the same. I find useful the following two options:

```
set hintkeys=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set! browser.tabs.closeButtons=2
```

Also - suppose Your FireFox aware of wikipedia search - and suppose it is called wikipedia-en. Then here's a way to bind search selection in wikipedia to a key:

```
javascript <<EOF
     dactyl.mulSearch = function () {
         let selection = content.getSelection().toString();
         dactyl.execute(":tabopen wikipedia-en " + selection);
     };
EOF

:map s -js dactyl.mulSearch();
```

(You should put this to ~/.pentadactylrc) This search selection after You'll press `s`. This way You can also bind other search engines - to the same key!

**Edit**:

```
" default place for downloads:
cd ~/dwn

" lots of hints!
set hintkeys=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

" no close buttons on tabs
set! browser.tabs.closeButtons=2

" May be default hints would suit You better - but they were to small for me:
:highlight Hint font:"DejaVu Sans Mono";font-size:120%;color:red;background-color:yellow;padding:2px;

" to prevent d on the last tab from closing the window:
:set! browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab=false

" encripted google - is better for hints (it has less links)
:bmark https://encrypted.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&complete=0&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%s -keyword google
set defsearch=google


" ==================
"" Cyrillic letters:

map Ф A
map И B
map С C
map В D
map У E
map А F
map П G
map Р H
map Ш I
map О J
map Л K
map Д L
map Ь M
map Т N
map Щ O
map З P
map Й Q
map К R
map Ы S
map Е T
map Г U
map М V
map Ц W
map Ч X
map Н Y
map Я Z
map ф a
map и b
map с c
map в d
map у e
map а f
map п g
map р h
map ш i
map о j
map л k
map д l
map ь m
map т n
map щ o
map з p
map й q
map к r
map ы s
map е t
map г u
map м v
map ц w
map ч x
map н y
map я z
```

Comment: Woops! Perhaps I'll never develop a habit of re-reading my writings!

Comment: `hintkeys` doens't appear to work in Vimperator. Instead it's like this: `set hintchars=asdfjk;l1234567890` (to set the home keys and numbers as the hint characters).

Answer (score 2):

I made some small changes. Made moving between tabs a single keystroke instead of two, since it is the most common thing I do next to clicking links and scrolling.

Also show visual indicator instead of beeping, and show the destination of the selected hyperlink in the command line instead of the status line, so that I can still see the URL of the current page at all times.

From my _vimperatorrc file:

```
" Mappings
map b gt
map B gT
map a B

" Options
set visualbell
set complete=hbsf
set showstatuslinks=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use *Pentadactyl*, but the below should work with *Vimperator* as well. I added several commands to enable searching through different sites like *DuckDuckGo* and *stackoverflow*.

You can add a new search engine with the following command:

```
:display searchengines
```

Add the *stackoverflow* search engine to make the below work.

Define a new command **stack** to search through *stackoverflow*:

```
:command -nargs=* stack open stack-overflow <args>
```

Now you can search through stackoverflow to get all vimperator related questions with the following command:

```
:stack vimperator
```

Make sure to issue

```
:mkpentadactylrc!
```

to make the command available after a restart of *Firefox*.

Answer (score 0):

```
"eval script in tabs
js <<EOF
function ExecScriptInTabs(filter,domjs){
     tabs.allTabs.forEach(function(itm){
    var ctab=gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(itm);
    if(filter(ctab)){
        var s=ctab.contentDocument.createElement('script')
        s.textContent=domjs;
        ctab.contentDocument.body.appendChild(s);
    }
     })
}
EOF
```

then you can mapping what you want

```
group.mappings.add(
[modes.NORMAL],
[",ds"],"skip",
function(){
ExecScriptInTabs(function(ctab){
return ctab.contentDocument.location.host.match("douban\.fm");
},"DBR.act('skip')");//skip,pause,love
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save session when using Alt+F4 or qall command

Add following line to your ~/.vimperatorrc

```
command! qall xall
```